# How to change values of panel on selecting a row in a table : jgoodies

Tags: swing, jgoodies

I am using Jgoodies binding to bind the table with my data. What listener i should implement so that when a cell is selected the values in a panel are changed.

My model class of table extends AbstractTableAdapter which is an Jgoodies binding class.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListSelectionModel` in your `JTable` (or suitable subclass) is what triggers events when the rows in a table are selected.  You can implement `ListSelectionListener` and grab the selection model from the `JTable` and add yourself as a listener.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do it as follows

```
myTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("hi");

        }
    });
```